Datalogger - Multiple CAN Bus
I have around 15 CAN Bus Interfaces (not connected to each other) sending data on the bus and I want to read all the data and forward to a PC (via USB or Ethernet).
I have looked into MCP2515. I will connect a Microcontroller to all the 15 MCP2515 ICs, get the CAN data from the Registers via SPI and send it to PC. In total, 15 MCP2515 + 1 Microcontroller would be present on the bus.
Is this an efficient solution to get CAN Data without any data loss?

The first part is a real question, but we can't answer it as we have no clue at what data rate your CAN buses run and how much there is traffic. Also you could consider how fast that data must flow through the SPI interfaces, and how many SPI interfaces you might need - 1, 2, 3, 4 or more. And then if the data rate of Ethernet variant or USB variant of your liking can handle it. And the final part you should edit out - asking if something you want to buy exists and from where to buy it is off topic.

Nobody but confused Arduino hobbyists uses MCP2515 this millennium unless they have very specialized requirements. Everyone uses microcontrollers with built-in CAN controllers. I'm not sure why you can't just use some 15 USB-to-CAN adapters already developed by someone else though.

Thanks for the suggestions. Based on feedback, either use a microcontroller with multiple CAN Inerfaces (diffcult to find one & costly) or use 15 USB-CAN adapters (costly and more space).

Why do you want to integrate 15 CAN interfaces into one microcontroller?

The R&D costs for making this product yourself will widely exceed the cost of 15 USB-to-CAN adapters... It's so tiresome with every single person on this site yells "too expensive" without thinking. Engineer salaries cost a lot of money. EMC and other 3rd party tests cost a lot of money. PCB prototypes + assembly (at least 2 board spins) cost a lot of money. If cost are that important then maybe you should actually consider the costs.

The vector VN1530 supports 4 CAN channels per PCIe card. With the addition of pyggiback modules it can support 6 channels. This is already plugged into a computer and does not require any additional interface.

Yes it will work great. You need to assemble multiple CAN messages with their partial timestamps into a single UDP packet and send it on the wire when it gets full or upon a timeout - say 1ms timeout. This means there will be a max of 1ms latency on transmit - nothing compared to the potential latency of the network stack in the OS.
A single UDP packet will start with a timestamp and a number of CAN messages. Then each CAN message will have a small delta timestamp between its reception timestamp and the UDP packet’s timestamp, and also the number of the CAN bus it came from.
You will surely keep multiple 1500-byte UDP packet skeletons in RAM and fill them as the CAN traffic comes, then send them out when they are full. You can also retransmit them several times if the bandwidth allows, to work around single packet drops. But this has to be optional since higher packet rate may make things worse on the receiving end.
To receive UDP traffic reliably in general you’ll want to use low latency networking APIs. On Windows that would be completion ports. And use pre-allocated receive buffers shared with hardware whenever the OS allows it. That means a page-aligned buffer in DMA-able address space that the network card can fill automatically without OS involvement and without copying the data. This will minimize the latency of the receive code, if that is a concern. For basic CAN data logging it’s unnecessary, just let the OS process completion handlers on a thread pool. Good networking libraries abstract all of this out.
But I bet you that you could write your receiving application in single-threaded Visual Basic 6 and it would still deal with the packet rate on modern hardware just fine. So don’t sweat it too much on the receive side. Only complicate things when tests show problems.

15 CAN bus channels will be an overwhelming stream of data without strict filtering in place. A reasonable speed can do thousands of messages per second.
If you want to correlate message timestamps accross all 15 receivers for correct representation of logged data for debugging purposes your project just became exponentially more complicated.
I'd recommend (renting?) a Kvaser memorator (5 channels) or finding another cheap USB-CAN device capable of interfacing with Python.

I disagree. 15 CAN buses will not overload a fast Ethernet connection. Ever. At full message load. The MCU is assembling multiple CAN messages into UDP frames and sends them whenever full or on timeout. Jumbo frame can save a bit of overhead but it’s not strictly necessary and must be optional. Most modern PCs will not even notice the load from consolidated packets from 15 CAN buses. One core may be a couple % above idle. CAN buses have puny bandwidth compared to what PCs are designed to deal with.

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica that's not the bit I was worried about. Showing you the data is.
